# Can't parse certificate after upgrading openssl on the client side

Tags: openssl, certificate, upgrade, asn.1

We've upgraded openssl on the client side from `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips` to `OpenSSL 1.1.1b`. The server side is running `Bouncy Castle 1.46`.

With `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips` on the client side, the server sends a certificate that looks like this:

```sh
PEM
---
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1553073698333 (0x1699a67f61d)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, CN=10.12.204.189
        Validity
            Not Before: May 21 05:38:35 2019 GMT
            Not After : May 20 21:00:00 2049 GMT
        Subject: 
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b7:7f:20:0c:21:a2:7a:79:4f:12:8b:cd:db:92:
                    b6:76:79:34:34:bc:6a:c0:c9:87:ab:1b:df:e9:a1:
                    ff:f0:de:6f:15:bd:5e:cb:f3:bf:fb:fd:06:9d:8b:
                    f1:62:28:48:e0:e1:bd:79:48:f8:53:a0:15:93:65:
                    c2:b6:b5:88:93:63:a7:47:44:7c:96:84:48:1d:ed:
                    49:09:0e:10:57:31:60:bb:7a:3b:8b:61:bd:47:3c:
                    8a:e6:0a:c1:86:f1:75:84:62:5a:05:6a:43:25:7d:
                    0b:40:33:68:ce:f8:07:71:52:8e:3d:d1:df:57:ee:
                    23:86:51:7f:d9:3e:0a:f8:19:b8:49:a5:2e:77:8a:
                    5c:8d:26:f9:3a:94:e0:dc:62:81:47:1b:e5:e4:da:
                    45:a4:2a:70:ed:61:50:68:b5:0f:b7:5f:d4:cd:36:
                    3f:85:6f:c8:cb:1b:7b:a0:ec:f1:3c:5e:d4:e0:08:
                    65:aa:4a:7e:88:05:cc:ac:45:4e:09:f2:36:d9:a9:
                    96:9f:05:9d:95:e6:37:f8:f7:3c:62:cb:0d:4a:1c:
                    4e:be:7e:15:d2:50:69:eb:65:16:11:f2:58:03:52:
                    6f:71:64:26:08:de:50:cc:52:c3:8a:b6:9a:9f:98:
                    56:6b:0d:85:4a:09:e2:e5:72:3b:cc:77:49:9c:90:
                    b5:f9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
..........0..   0.."0
....... .!.zyO......vy44.j...........o..^.........b(H...yH.S...e.....c.GD|..H..I...W1`.z;.a.G<..
...u.bZ.jC%}.@3h...qR.=..W.#.Q..>
.J...r;.wI.........d&..P.R......Vk_..6?.o...{...<^...e.J~....EN..6........7..<b.
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         ab:b6:5d:1a:cb:9d:4c:44:6c:50:a5:fd:dc:b7:88:a3:37:51:
         d1:aa:7b:a5:75:7b:8f:14:1e:fd:c1:72:c9:9c:a3:51:38:92:
         6b:03:68:4d:52:41:df:21:b7:3f:b7:47:5b:36:df:19:5d:6f:
         92:e0:b8:2b:8c:de:0c:b0:f1:7d:a5:cf:11:28:a0:a3:84:5f:
         1c:e9:01:1b:c8:e6:be:06:81:22:85:c5:cf:de:e1:97:2f:ae:
         92:ff:41:69:07:cc:fb:39:c9:5a:47:aa:32:01:8f:9f:9e:c3:
         eb:c4:83:97:b1:a9:04:78:d1:a3:57:74:a9:63:96:07:b2:81:
         ec:ec:8f:be:32:30:20:af:2d:45:3e:44:48:3c:ab:77:47:18:
         0d:a8:0e:ca:60:cf:12:93:82:ea:13:20:82:25:aa:89:3e:15:
         83:38:8e:84:47:e0:de:be:87:e3:bf:f2:b1:1c:06:75:9e:3e:
         6d:eb:6e:6d:2c:36:76:fe:1a:05:84:8e:ce:1b:36:8b:02:41:
         21:22:6e:80:a1:a1:60:d4:93:63:d3:cd:d1:f5:26:16:83:ed:
         7b:3c:74:f1:54:2b:64:3f:ae:ee:8f:60:30:e0:1b:0b:38:27:
         7a:b0:f8:d0:c2:08:f6:55:7e:a6:97:ee:4f:b6:b9:ca:f6:eb:
         60:bc:64:4d

ANS.1
-----
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 990 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 710 cons: SEQUENCE          
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
   10:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02
   13:d=2  hl=2 l=   6 prim: INTEGER           :01699A67F61D
   21:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEncryption
   34:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   36:d=2  hl=2 l=  37 cons: SEQUENCE          
   38:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET               
   40:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
   42:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :countryName
   47:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :US
   51:d=3  hl=2 l=  22 cons: SET               
   53:d=4  hl=2 l=  20 cons: SEQUENCE          
   55:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
   60:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTF8STRING        :10.12.204.189
   75:d=2  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE          
   77:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :190521053835Z
   92:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :490520210000Z
  107:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE          
  109:d=2  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
  113:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  115:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  126:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  128:d=3  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING        
  403:d=2  hl=4 l= 311 cons: cont [ 3 ]        
  407:d=3  hl=4 l= 307 cons: SEQUENCE          
  411:d=4  hl=4 l= 303 cons: SEQUENCE          
  415:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Key Identifier
  420:d=5  hl=4 l= 294 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: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
  718:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  720:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEncryption
  731:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  733:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: BIT STRING
```

With `OpenSSL 1.1.1b` on the client side, the server sends a certificate that looks like this:

```sh
PEM
---
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1553073698340 (0x1699a67f624)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, CN=10.12.204.189
        Validity
            Not Before: May 21 07:05:20 2019 GMT
            Not After : May 20 21:00:00 2049 GMT
        Subject:
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a6:bc:b2:26:4e:76:9f:0d:40:25:2c:0a:aa:6a:
                    67:ba:31:fc:09:8b:7d:d1:de:13:73:11:8a:d6:9d:
                    68:55:b2:74:66:09:9c:b3:db:a0:ab:46:42:5d:ba:
                    6b:d6:97:3c:fd:88:cf:de:55:8d:bd:74:1c:6e:19:
                    13:fb:93:86:11:54:55:b6:f5:8d:2f:62:5e:2b:07:
                    b4:ac:d3:bb:30:51:17:61:56:35:19:5a:cc:f0:f3:
                    e7:1a:13:f2:5b:f8:45:c5:5b:4c:a9:3a:6a:4b:26:
                    25:fc:38:4e:be:b2:ac:41:31:52:ee:64:76:7b:fd:
                    6a:81:87:08:1c:8c:c8:f4:17:3e:58:08:45:90:db:
                    6e:11:05:8e:48:3a:8d:82:77:63:4e:23:a4:a4:d6:
                    94:a5:89:1a:91:41:71:c9:e3:76:b8:c3:71:b0:e7:
                    94:68:04:ee:1f:c9:e6:b1:67:d7:4c:b3:ee:b4:11:
                    22:f4:36:5f:54:4d:0d:d1:cf:72:d7:73:ed:80:49:
                    09:ff:a4:e9:93:f6:29:4b:96:b1:59:d2:3c:fe:04:
                    3a:16:dd:17:49:20:b9:dc:80:42:a4:b6:14:55:1e:
                    5c:bd:90:bb:fe:14:2a:6a:38:63:f3:09:b1:60:57:
                    85:f0:58:fe:b6:dd:da:17:4d:58:43:49:ee:49:63:
                    00:4f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
..........0..   0.."0
@%,.....&Nv.
..r.s..I......)K..Y.<..:...I ...B...U.\.....*j8c...`W..X.....MXCI.Ic.O...........[.E.[L.:jK&%.8N...A1R.dv{.j........>X.E..n...H:..wcN#........Aq..v..q...h......g.L....".6_TM
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         6d:7a:aa:de:d5:cf:74:6d:3e:b4:04:5f:27:0d:17:cf:2e:eb:
         43:f6:a2:5e:9f:c8:f5:2d:10:ec:4b:c2:04:6f:47:f7:3c:30:
         3f:46:89:3d:91:a9:fe:60:f5:a6:b7:40:31:59:ec:f1:f8:e1:
         ab:36:7b:ce:10:6e:cb:94:05:d6:c9:c2:27:9c:3f:d6:d7:49:
         48:4e:83:d1:fc:06:4d:9d:19:11:2a:f9:7c:8b:0f:7e:da:21:
         91:de:93:95:16:e0:96:a2:e3:a5:27:bf:dd:ae:ec:1a:25:e2:
         59:2c:4f:2c:b6:91:34:4e:46:6b:bc:75:c7:39:58:f4:b4:1a:
         c7:d2:cc:ae:59:2c:fd:6f:d7:30:98:ba:f5:8f:eb:f8:dc:62:
         f0:48:35:d3:0b:da:ee:b9:6e:20:b8:87:a9:ed:a7:db:38:eb:
         86:ed:1d:8d:00:fd:25:7f:fd:37:c7:4a:f3:46:95:94:1c:6f:
         46:8e:46:3e:5c:97:1f:11:d3:7e:d4:70:2c:92:e6:4e:6a:40:
         d0:bf:0d:48:19:c8:f7:ba:35:b1:62:d4:58:17:fa:7d:e5:12:
         af:fe:eb:ac:e6:f4:5e:91:9d:58:c9:1f:1c:a2:32:ff:06:a1:
         82:bf:3b:39:e9:27:a7:bc:2b:7c:ab:4d:b2:5c:82:77:2c:c7:
         d8:76:10:a4

ASN.1
-----
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 990 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 710 cons: SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 cons: cont [ 0 ]
   10:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :02
   13:d=2  hl=2 l=   6 prim: INTEGER           :01699A67F624
   21:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEncryption
   34:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   36:d=2  hl=2 l=  37 cons: SEQUENCE
   38:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET
   40:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE
   42:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :countryName
   47:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :US
   51:d=3  hl=2 l=  22 cons: SET
   53:d=4  hl=2 l=  20 cons: SEQUENCE
   55:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
   60:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTF8STRING        :10.12.204.189
   75:d=2  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE
   77:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :190521070520Z
   92:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim: UTCTIME           :490520210000Z
  107:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE
  109:d=2  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE
  113:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
  115:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  126:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
  128:d=3  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING
  403:d=2  hl=4 l= 311 cons: cont [ 3 ]
  407:d=3  hl=4 l= 307 cons: SEQUENCE
  411:d=4  hl=4 l= 303 cons: SEQUENCE
  415:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Key Identifier
  420:d=5  hl=4 l= 294 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: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
  718:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
  720:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEncryption
  731:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
  733:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: BIT STRING
```

They are very similar if you ask me, and yet our existing unchanged flow fails when it calls:

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ssl_ctx, "certificate.crt");
```

The error message from openssl is:

```sh
error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
```

Should we sign the certificate differently somehow? Or change some other field?

Which tag went wrong?

**EDIT** Added PEM formats of the certificates. The server doesn't use openssl at all, it uses Bouncy Castle 1.46 in java

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add the certificate (in pem format) so that people can repro your issue.

Comment: sure, done . ***

Comment: I meat the contains of the certificate file (which is a text file) on the server.  That way I can reproduce the problem with openssl myself.  If I can reproduce the problem I can debug it and tell you why it's doing what it's doing.

Comment: I don't want the private key part of the certificate. Just the public key part.

Comment: That link wants me to sign in...

Comment: strange. never mind though. i found my own answer by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how the server was using bouncy castle in adding the **X509v3 Subject Key Identifier** to the certificate's **X509v3 extensions**.

Instead of doing:

```java
x509v3CertificateBuilder.addExtension(X509Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, pk10Holder.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
```

Which produces garbage:

```sh
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
..........0..   0.."0
@%,.....&Nv.
..r.s..I......)K..Y.<..:...I ...B...U.\.....*j8c...`W..X.....MXCI.Ic.O...........[.E.[L.:jK&%.8N...A1R.dv{.j........>X.E..n...H:..wcN#........Aq..v..q...h......g.L....".6_TM
```

Do:

```java
x509v3CertificateBuilder.addExtension(X509Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(inputCSR.getPublicKey()));
```

Which produces a proper hash of the certificate:

```sh
X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                10:47:60:D7:98:D5:3C:D6:AC:66:FC:17:B4:F5:44:15:7B:AF:0B:D1
```